# How to pull image from private Docker registry in KubernetesPodOperator of Google Cloud Composer?

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to run a task in an environment built from an image in a private Google Container Registry through the KubernetesPodOperator of the Google Cloud Composer.
The Container Registry and Cloud Composer instances are under the same project.
My code is below.

```
import datetime
import airflow
from airflow.contrib.operators import kubernetes_pod_operator


YESTERDAY = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


# Create Airflow DAG the the pipeline
with airflow.DAG(
        'my_dag',
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1),
        start_date=YESTERDAY) as dag:

    my_task = kubernetes_pod_operator.KubernetesPodOperator(
        task_id='my_task',
        name='my_task',
        cmds=['echo 0'],
        namespace='default',
        image=f'gcr.io/<my_private_repository>/<my_image>:latest')
```

The task fails and I get the following error message in the logs in the Airflow UI and in the `logs` folder in the storage bucket.

```
[2020-09-21 08:39:12,675] {taskinstance.py:1147} ERROR - Pod Launching failed: Pod returned a failure: failed
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator.py", line 260, in execut
    'Pod returned a failure: {state}'.format(state=final_state
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Pod returned a failure: failed
```

This not very informative...
Any idea what I could be doing wrong?
Or anywhere I can find more informative log messages?

Thank you very much!

Comment: As you're aware, the Error you've given doesn't give much information about the actual failure. I could take a guess and say `cmds=['echo', '0']` might be worth trying.If that doesn't work you might try invoking the pod via Python interface or modules directly, or via Kubernetes directly and read the output from there and sharing the error text from that work in this chat once you have it

Answer (score 1):

In general, the way how we start troubleshooting GCP Composer once getting a failure running the DAG is finely explained in the dedicated [chapter](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/troubleshooting-dags) of GCP documentation.

Moving to [KubernetesPodOperator](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator) specifically related issues, the certain user investigation might consists of:

- Verifying the particular [*task status*](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator#task-status) for the corresponded DAG
  file;
- Inspecting the task inventory [*logs and events;*](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator#task-logs), logs also can be found in GCP Composer's [storage bucket](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/logs#logs_in);
- With any K8s related [resource/objects](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/using-logs#resource_types) errors it's strongly
  required to check Composer's relevant [GKE cluster](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/using-logs#finding_your_logs_in_logs_viewer) log/event
  journals.

Further analyzing the error context and `KubernetesPodOperator.py` source code, I assume that this issue might occur due to Pod launching problem on Airflow worker GKE node, ending up with `Pod returned a failure: {state}'.format(state=final_state)` message once the Pod execution is not successful.

Personally, I prefer to check the image run in prior executing Airflow task in a Kubernetes Pod. Having said this and based on the task command provided, I believe that you can verify the Pod launching process, [*connecting to GKE*](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/deploy-webserver#connect-cluster) cluster and redrafting `kubernetes_pod_operator.KubernetesPodOperator` definition being adoptable for `kubectl`  command-line executor:

```
kubectl run test-app --image=eu.gcr.io/<Project_ID>/image --command -- "/bin/sh" "-c" "echo 0"
```

This would simplify the process of image validation, hence you'll be able to get closer look at Pod logs or event records as well:

```
kubectl describe po test-app
```

Or

```
kubectl logs test-app
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pull or push an image in `KubernetesPodOperator` from private registry, you should [create](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/) a Secret in k8s which contains a service account (SA). This SA should have permission for pulling or maybe pushing images (RO/RW permission).

Then just use this secret with SA in `KubernetesPodOperator` and specify `image_pull_secrets` [argument](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/kubernetes_pod.py#L180):

```
my_task = kubernetes_pod_operator.KubernetesPodOperator(
    task_id='my_task',
    name='my_task',
    cmds=['echo 0'],
    namespace='default',
    image=f'gcr.io/<my_private_repository>/<my_image>:latest',
    image_pull_secrets='your_secret_name')
```